# Divshot static container width with Bootstrap

Tags: divshot

Is it possible to define fixed container widths in Divshot, if so where?

Trying to make a 960px based site which isn't used for mobile.

I would like the container fixed so its children fill it but don't resize with the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

We include the Bootstrap responsive styles by default (and as of Bootstrap 3 it will be baked into the framework). When you export your code you can remove the extra call but at present there is no option to do so.